# Check Time Control and change color in listrCtrl

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

In the part of the code included between ################ Code ######### I try to do a control with if but doesn't work.
I would like that when the variable 'ts' is equal to the variable 'prova' the line(item) in the same list ctrl becomes red. For all item which I insert in the ctrl list. Thanks so much!

```
import wx
import wx.gizmos as gizmos
import time
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

class CWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ wx.CLOSE_BOX ^ wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER, size=(600,500))

        dataCorrente = datetime.datetime.now()

        self.Panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.index = 0

        self.CTesto = wx.TextCtrl(self.Panel, 1, pos=(10,40), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.CTesto.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER,self.add_line)

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(self.Panel, pos=(10,90),size=(-1,300),style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Name')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Time START')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Time FINISH', width=100)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)


        self.led = gizmos.LEDNumberCtrl(self.Panel, -1, pos = (350,25), size = (200,50), style = gizmos.LED_ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.led.SetBackgroundColour("#c0c0c0")
        self.led.SetForegroundColour("black")
        self.OnTimer(None)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, -1)
        self.timer.Start(1000)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer)
        style = gizmos.LED_ALIGN_CENTER


    def OnTimer(self, event):

        current = time.localtime(time.time())
        global ts
        ts = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", current)
        self.led.SetValue(ts)
        #print (ts) # In Loop it's OK

############################################################################################################################

        if ts == prova:
            self.list_ctrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(self.index, wx.RED)


############################################################################################################################

    def add_line(self,event):

        val = str(self.CTesto.GetValue())

        if val== '':

            msg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Error", "Error", wx.OK| wx.ICON_ERROR)
            msg.ShowModal()
            msg.Destroy()

        else:

            dataCorrente = datetime.datetime.now()
            oraAttuale =(dataCorrente.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            plus = (datetime.datetime.strptime(oraAttuale, "%H:%M:%S") + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1))
            global plus2
            plus2 = plus.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

            self.list_ctrl.InsertItem(self.index, val)
            self.list_ctrl.SetItem(self.index, 1, oraAttuale)
            self.list_ctrl.SetItem(self.index, 2, str(plus2))
            self.index += 1


            InsVal = (val + " - " + oraAttuale + " - " + plus2 + '\n')
            self.CTesto.Clear()

            print (InsVal)

        prova = InsVal[-9:]

app = wx.App()  
frame = CWindow(None, -1, "Example")
frame.Show()
frame.Center()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`repr()` is your friend in this question.
`print(repr(self.prova))` would reveal that it contains a newline character, so that needs to be `stripped` off.
Also note that the `ListCtrl` index is zero based, so to apply the colour, you have to use `index - 1`.
With these minor adjustments your code works, as I hope you planned it to.

```
import wx
import wx.gizmos as gizmos
import time
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

class CWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ wx.CLOSE_BOX ^ wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER, size=(600,500))

        dataCorrente = datetime.datetime.now()

        self.Panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.index = 0
        self.prova = {}
        self.ts = ""

        self.CTesto = wx.TextCtrl(self.Panel, 1, pos=(10,40), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.CTesto.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER,self.add_line)

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(self.Panel, pos=(10,90),size=(-1,300),style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Name')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Time START')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Time FINISH', width=100)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)


        self.led = gizmos.LEDNumberCtrl(self.Panel, -1, pos = (350,25), size = (200,50), style = gizmos.LED_ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.led.SetBackgroundColour("#c0c0c0")
        self.led.SetForegroundColour("black")
        self.OnTimer(None)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self, -1)
        self.timer.Start(1000)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer)
        style = gizmos.LED_ALIGN_CENTER


    def OnTimer(self, event):

        current = time.localtime(time.time())
        self.ts = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", current)
        self.led.SetValue(self.ts)

############################################################################################################################

        if self.ts in self.prova:
            self.list_ctrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(self.prova.pop(self.ts), wx.RED)

############################################################################################################################

    def add_line(self,event):

        val = str(self.CTesto.GetValue())

        if val== '':

            msg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Error", "Error", wx.OK| wx.ICON_ERROR)
            msg.ShowModal()
            msg.Destroy()

        else:

            dataCorrente = datetime.datetime.now()
            oraAttuale =(dataCorrente.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            plus = (datetime.datetime.strptime(oraAttuale, "%H:%M:%S") + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1))
            plus2 = plus.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

            if plus2 in self.prova:
                msg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Duplicated Time", "Error", wx.OK| wx.ICON_ERROR)
                msg.ShowModal()
                msg.Destroy()
                return
            self.list_ctrl.InsertItem(self.index, val)
            self.list_ctrl.SetItem(self.index, 1, oraAttuale)
            self.list_ctrl.SetItem(self.index, 2, str(plus2))
            self.index += 1


            InsVal = (val + " - " + oraAttuale + " - " + plus2 + '\n')
            self.CTesto.Clear()

        self.prova[plus2] = self.index -1

app = wx.App()
frame = CWindow(None, -1, "Example")
frame.Show()
frame.Center()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Edit:
If you want to test for all of the entries, turning them red as they occur, you will have to change the nature of `prova`.
One way would be to make `prova` a `dictionary` and use the edited code above.
This provides a method to prevent duplicate entries and a simple method for deleting entries in the dictionary `prova` reducing the amount of checking required. In this way the code can run continuously for days without hitting duplicates. The dictionary entries are the `Finish` time and the listctrl's index value, used to perform the highlighting.
The act of deleting the `dictionary` entry (`pop`), returns the index number for the highlight.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfect, but if I insert the second item the first item it's not checked, because the control is only to the final item insert.

Comment: @Classic27794 Yep! That's the way you coded it, with `prova` being a single string. See my amended answer.

Comment: @Classic27794 I've edited my answer again, turning `prova` into a dictionary. The reasoning for this is in the edit.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain the difference with prova modification? What changes compared to before?

Comment: and i have a problem with this line code: 

self.list_ctrl.SetItemTextColour(self.ceck.pop(self.ts), wx.WHITE)

it worked before with the first solution.

Comment: @Classic27794 There is no such line of code above. I can only assume that you are referring to code that you have added.

Comment: Yes, i added in a second moment, but in the first solution it's work without problem, in this new solution give an error. How can i set the color white to the text? Thks!

Comment: @Classic27794 I don't know! I cannot see the error message and I can't see the code or its context. Is `self.ceck` a dictionary with the same structure as `self.prova`?

Comment: Sorry self.ceck is equal to self.prova it's the same var. I translate the name of var, but it's the same. self.list_ctrl.SetItemTextColour(self.prova.pop(self.ts), wx.WHITE)

Comment: This is the error: line 52, in OnTimer
self.list_ctrl.SetItemTextColour(self.prova.pop(self.ts), wx.WHITE)
KeyError: '10:38:12'

Comment: @Classic27794 I can only assume, still not knowing what the error message is, that you are referencing that variable after having already `popped` it once i.e. pop = delete, so it is no longer there.

Comment: @Classic27794 So use `self.prova.get(self.ts)` the first time and `pop` the 2nd time.

Comment: @Classic27794 The `index` is used to position it i.e. always use zero but then you are using the index to decide what needs to have its colour changed. You would have to radicaly rethink the way that your code works.